# Texture painting add-ons? adding levels ? straight lines?

Tags: texture-painting

So I was texturing this sword to learn how handpainting works, and now that I have kind of got how it works. I was wondering if there was a list of add-ons to make texture painting faster in blender. I don't like using gimp nor any other external tools, I prefer colouring directly on the model. I'm particularly interested in adding transparent levels to the UV and maybe some addons that allow drawing in geometry, like adding straight lines of color or different 2D shapes.

[image]

Comment: Addons for painting in Blender have had a hard time because of the changes in the python, but one of the best that might still be supported is BPainter https://blendermarket.com/products/bpainter/

Comment: For straight lines, look to the Stroke types where you can use Curve, Line, Drag Dot etc. https://youtu.be/nW-MaJ99IxU